# Laravel , search eloquent in balde

Tags: php, laravel

I have this question , let say i did this eloquent :

> $users =  Users::all();

and in balde i did this :

> @php ( $active_users =  $users->where('is_active' , '=' , 1))

> @php ( $not_active_users =  $users->where('is_active' , '=' , 0))

on blade do we request again the data from database , i.e. 2 database request?

Comment: u did only 1 query

Comment: Yes, It is possible

Comment: no you don't. what you are using now is the `where` method in `collection` since the `User::all()` returns a collection.